# VS 2012 Problems with gl/glut.h include with GLUT INSTALLED

Tags: opengl

I have some problems with the gl libraries: our teacher gave us a zip folder with all the tools for the gl libraries, to be unzipped in C: .
The problem is that when I try to copy files in System32 and SysWOW64, the writing permission is denied(even if I am the administrator and only user of the computer).
I've tried to change the permission giving to all users and administrator the full control, but it doesn't seem to change. Also, in System32 when I go to properties---Security ect, it doesn't let me change the permissions.
I checked in System32 and SysWOW64, all libraries and dll are already present(and i don't know why if I do not have writing permissions); also, I changed preferences on my C++ project adding opengl32.lib, glu32.lib and glut32.lib to Project -> Properties--> Linker -> Input  then modify Additional Dependencies field, but still doesn't work and give me the same error: "Cannot open source file gl/glut.h" .
Operating System: windows 8.1 .
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with the linker. What your get is a compiler error. To fix it, you have to adjust the "Additional Include Directories" (C++ -> General) to point to the folder where the gl folder containing glut.h is located.

Since you are getting an compiler error, the linker has not been called yet, so you might also have to add the directory containing your libraries in Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories.